# Windows 7 Printer Installation Loop

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer, shared-printers

I've installed a new printer in one my client server running Windows Server 2008 R2
configured the logon script to run at every login making it able to connect to every user whoever logs in. Recently i started to face this issue, a canon printer installs the drivers and a popup ask for me to restart and it goes on every single time when i login it happens whether i am an administrator or user this has become quite problem to me lately.
strange thing is they also run couple of Windows XP SP3 machines too it runs fine on them this issue is only with Windows 7.

Is there any way to tackle this issue?

[image]

Comment: How are you adding the printer in the script?

Comment: @MDMarra I just added a snippet below have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script is installing a software package that requires a reboot.

Are you able to simply add the printer using "net use LPT1 \MyServer\MyPrinter"  This would normally add the printer and then the driver is installed from the print server.

If the software package is needed, it should only need to be installed once and your script could be written to check for the installed software and not run if detected.

Comment: I just do this to add i use this command 
`rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n \\bsra-server\Canon_3300` and to set it as default i use this `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\bsra-server\Canon_3300`.. Do you think it's a problem